# iPhone: need simplest way to handle iOS navigation

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

I have a fairly big app made with all view-controllers connected by storyboard segues, before I realized that navigation buttons is a requirement.
I am at a point where I can no longer delete all scenes and start over, nor I can extend the segue approach because its quite overused.

I am looking up for small, elegant solution that will allow all my view controllers to have backward navigation. See my scene hierarchy:

- Page 1---> Page 2
- Page 1---> Page 3 ---> Page 4
- Page 3---> Page 5 and so on.

So I should be able to go back from Page 5 to Page 1 backwards.
I have about 12 screens as of now.

What should I do?
Can I safely mess up with storyboard?
Or should I add code snippets to my viewDidLoads and so on to handle the stuff?

My problem is that when I searched the solution, I found too many approaches including navigation controllers, uinavigationbar, UIBarButtonItem and so on. With each of them, I find it maybe too much for my need, and I need a smaller thing that may just work.

All I may need is only back buttons as of now, but with minimal effort - as I am quite tight on deadline :-(

Appreciate quick help.

Comment: Anyone, please? I have a scene which I must handle via navigation controller / bar because if I don't have, I must add segues to/from it  with every other screens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer from apple docs - basically I needed an approach to handle things (instead of straight code), and here it is:

- Initialize navcontroller in appdelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method, with root view controller set to first view controller of the app
- set appdelegate window's rootviewcontroller = navcontroller
- with every 'forward' navigation - use pushViewController along with target view controller
- there is no need to handle backward navigation - navcontroller takes care of it by default.

Above will also add extra navigation bar on top of every view controller (except the root view controller of the app's delegate).